# How do I set my own parameter in routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm running a script inside my file that generates content from the database and displays it through javascript depending on whats pulled out it goes like this

`<% Route.find(params[:plant_site]) do |route| %>`

But when I type localhost/findme/search word I only get it to return one and when I check the rails server it says LIMIT 1 how do I pull them all then iterate through them?

It seems to only pull the first

In my routes I have

`match '/findme/:plant_site'  => 'Locates#show'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route.find(params[:plant_site])
```

will return the first item it finds. Try this,

```
# /app/controllers/the_controller.rb

def the_action
  @routes = Route.where(id: params[:plant_site]).all
end


# /app/views/the_controller/the_action.html.erb

<% @routes.each do |route| %>
  <%= ... %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT:**

Although the `id` column will usually be a primary key column so the above will still return only 1 result. Try `Route.where(plant_site: params[:plant_site])` maybe. I'm guessing the column is `:plant_site`.

**EDIT:**

Added file names to indicate where code should go from beck03076's comment.

Comment: How come you specified id:?

Comment: Because the `Route.find(...)` in the question will find by `id` so I assumed the column would be `id`. Just change the `id:` to the correct column name. I've also added a bit more info to my answer.

Comment: oh ok, that worked great thanks I'll give you a check as soon as im able too, So Route.where will find everything in column plant:site with the parameter :plant_site?

Comment: Yes, the `where` method will return an array matching the query and `find` will return the first result with the `id` matching the first argument.

Comment: @beck03076 how do I put it in the controller and then use it in the JS?

Comment: @Sam, DHH will be happy, to see that!